# Android ConstraintLayout - How to move view to occupied space?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Please look at this image and this is what i currently have created:

[image]

but my issue is at some point the color segment may become invisible or gone. and at this time i need the size segment to move into the same place as the color segment. How can i do this ? Basically, i would like the size segment to take the place of the color segment in the case that is its invisible/gone.

I tried creating a guideline but that is constant and does not move.  I wonder if a barrier would work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways of doing that. One that only uses XML but is less flexible and second that requires some changes in code and gives more control over the `Views`. Note that both of these will only work when the color segment's visibility is set to `GONE`, as views that are `INVISIBLE` still ocupy space.

1. We set the width percent for both views to 50%. When the Color
   segment is `GONE` the Size segment will slide to the left because of
   the horizontal bias. This solution might not work well if you set
   margins for these views as they have a fixed size of 50% of the
   available width of the layout.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/color"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Color"
           app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"/>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/size"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Size"
           app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/color"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"/>

   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
   ```
2. We put both views in a weighted chain but also add a `Space` helper
   to it to act as the filler of the remaining space when the 'Color'
   view is `GONE`. The views that are visible both have weights of
   `0.5`, each taking up half of the available space. The `Space`
   helper has weight of `0` and is therefore not visible.

   The XML:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/layout">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/color"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Color"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/size"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
           app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"/>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/size"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Size"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/space"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/color"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"/>

       <Space
           android:id="@+id/space"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/size"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0"/>

   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
   ```

   Now when you need to hide your Color segment you would do something
   like this:

   ```
   ConstraintSet cs = new ConstraintSet();
   ConstraintLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
   Space space = findViewById(R.id.space);
   TextView color = findViewById(R.id.color);
   cs.clone(layout);
   cs.setHorizontalWeight(space.getId(), 0.5f);
   cs.applyTo(layout);
   color.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   ```

   This will make the Color segment disappear, but the Size segment
   will slide to the left because the constraints are preserved even
   then a view's visibility is set to `GONE`. The `Space` has its
   weight set to `0.5` and will take the right half of the space.

Comment: #1 can also be done with linearlayout weights.  thanks for your great help.